# Randomly generate points on a van der Waals surface

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, regions

I'm looking to randomly place an atom $\mathbf{A}$ onto a van der Waals surface formed by atoms $\mathbf{B}$, such that the distance between the randomly-generated atom $\mathbf{A}$ and the nearest surface atom $\mathbf{B}_i$ is equal to the sum of the van der Waals radii $r$. Essentially, the problem boils down to a sphere rolling around on an uneven surface.

I can generate a van der Waals surface for graphene with the following code:

```
latticeGenerate[basisvec_List, numofcell_List, base_List] := 
 Module[{x, y, basex, basey}, {x, y} = 
   Transpose[Tuples[Range /@ numofcell].basisvec];
  {basex, basey} = Transpose[base];
  Transpose[{Join @@ ((x + #) & /@ basex), 
    Join @@ ((y + #) & /@ basey)}]]
```

Defining the C-C bond length and van der Waals radius,

```
a = 1.4145;
rc = 1.675;

carbonXYZ = Flatten[{#, 0}] & /@ 
   latticeGenerate[{{3 a, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3] a}}, {5,7}, 
      {{0, 0}, {a, 0}, {-a/2, Sqrt[3] a/2}, {3 a/2, Sqrt[3] a/2}}];

vdWsurf = Sphere[carbonXYZ, rc];
Graphics3D[{Gray, vdWsurf}, PlotRangePadding -> 2, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

I'd then like to place an atom with radius 2.5 at random on the top of this surface, e.g.

[image]

I did think about a naive approach using `FindInstance[]`, but this just runs for a long time without a result:

```
ra = 2.5;
minDist[pt_] := Min[Sqrt[(#.#)] & /@ (Transpose[Transpose[carbonXYZ] - pt])]
FindInstance[minDist[{x, y, z}] == (ra + rc) &&
                       5 < x < 15 && 5 < y < 15 && 0 < z < 5,
                       {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

Could the `Region[]` functionality of *Mathematica* be exploited here? I'm looking to generate lots of these systems, so speed is of the essence! Perhaps `RandomPoint[]` can be utilised in this case?

Comment: Aren't you already aware of `RandomPoint`?

Comment: For example, set `s = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[Min[EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ carbonXYZ] == rc + ra, {x, y, z}], {{-1, 28}, {-2, 23}, {-5, 5}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]` and then `RandomPoint[s]` is extremely fast.

Comment: @Rahul your comment is surely deserving of being an answer!

Comment: @Rahul I was aware of `RandomPoint`, but not of how to apply it!

Comment: @Rahul as Oleksandr says, if you make your comment an answer, it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Rahul:

```
s = DiscretizeRegion[
        ImplicitRegion[
          Min[EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ carbonXYZ] == rc + ra, 
        {x, y, z}], 
       {{-1, 28}, {-2, 23}, {-5, 5}}, 
       MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1] 

RandomPoint[s]
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to set it up as a minimization problem. For example:

```
NMinimize[(minDist[{x, y, z}] - (ra + rc))^2, 5<x<15 && 5<y<15 && 0<z<5, {x, y, z}]

{2.43076*10^-21, {x -> 7.32182, y -> 13.4219, z -> 4.14947}}
```

You can find minima in different locations by changing the constraints:

```
NMinimize[(minDist[{x, y, z}] - (ra + rc))^2, 5<x<6 && 5<y<15 && 0<z< 5, {x, y, z}]

{7.66876*10^-19, {x -> 5.50514, y -> 13.7025, z -> 4.0791}}
```

Alternatively, `FindMinimum` seems faster, and allows you to directly give an initial point:

```
FindMinimum[{(minDist[{x, y, z}] - (ra + rc))^2, 5<x<15 && 5<y<15 && 0<z<5},
            {{x, 10}, {y, 10}, {z, 2.5}}]

{1.21243*10^-12, {x -> 10.2024, y -> 10.4351, z -> 4.11543}}
```

In line with Oleksandr's comments, you can also try

```
FindMinimum[(minDist[{x, y, z}] - (ra + rc))^2, 
            {{x, 8.}, {y, 10}, {z, 3.5}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

Try out the different methods, some of which may give you warnings (and require adjusting various parameters).

Comment: I think I would try `FindMinimum` without the constraints if speed is important. If constraints are given it uses the nonlinear interior point algorithm, which is (the only one?) written in top-level code, and slow. Since all of its methods are local optimizers, you can rely on it not going far from the starting point.